# Wordpress redirect non-valid subdomains to homepage

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Is there a way without knowing ahead of time if a subdomain is valid?

As of now non-valid domains go to a registration page which is turned off. Specifically users are taken to example.com/wp-signup if a subdomain does not exist; i want this to go to example.com when this happens.

What is the best way to handle this? I have not found any relevant posts on SO for this.

EDIT:

My installation is multisite, so I need something that can redirect based on the base domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://example.com' );
```

In your wp-config.php file.  That should redirect all of those to where you want them to go.

Good luck.

Comment: How would I handle a multisite install? This only works for one of the multisites.